# how to do long way searching in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a table and want to do a searching in mysql using only one query. Here is the screenshot for table:

[image]

If the search string is

> New Delhi BBA Management Dhaula Kuan

Then it should return data_id 3. I want to know the searching technique for a long database. Thanks for the help.

Comment: use like operator to search

Comment: please explain me how?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE data_city LIKE '%$variable%' OR data_area LIKE '$variable%' OR dara_category LIKE '%$variable%'"

Comment: [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) is probably what you will want to use.

Comment: Please don't dump lengthy code in comments @MayankVadiya

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',data_city,data_category,data_area)
FROM table_name 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',data_city,data_category,data_area) LIKE '%New%BBA%Dhau%';
```